# Initializing TableLayout in XML and programmatically filling it - Android (java)

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout

I am trying to initialize a TableLayout in XML and then fill it in programmatically.  Here is my XML, java and LogCat output.

Highscores.java

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    TableLayout table;
    TableRow rowHeader, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10;
    TextView rank, percentage, score;
    Button btn1;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoresmain);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        TextView rank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
        rank.setText("RANK");
        TextView percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        percentage.setText("PERCENTAGE");
        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        score.setText("SCORE");

        TableRow rowHeader = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.rowHeader);

        rowHeader.addView(rank);  //Line 39
        rowHeader.addView(percentage);
        rowHeader.addView(score);

        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);

        table.addView(rowHeader, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Highscores.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

highscoresmain.xml

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rowHeader">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
```

LogCat

```
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at com.example.test.Highscores.onCreate(Highscores.java:39)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-19 06:03:36.960: E/AndroidRuntime(20130):    ... 11 more
```

What I want is a simple 3 column table with row 1 headings being "RANK", "PERCENTAGE" AND "SCORE".  Later I will have 10 more rows that I will pull from a SQLite database but I will tackle that afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xml file will be editting;

I am trying to initialize a TableLayout in XML and then fill it in programmatically. Here is my XML, java and LogCat output.

highscoresmain.xml

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:padding="5dp">


   </TableLayout>
```

Highscores class content;

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    TableLayout table;
    TableRow rowHeader, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10;
    TextView rank, percentage, score;
    Button btn1;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoresmain);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        TextView rank = new TextView(this);
        rank.setText("RANK");
        TextView percentage = new TextView(this);
        percentage.setText("PERCENTAGE");
        TextView score = new TextView(this);
        score.setText("SCORE");

        TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(this);

        rowHeader.addView(rank);  //Line 39
        rowHeader.addView(percentage);
        rowHeader.addView(score);

        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);

        table.addView(rowHeader);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Highscores.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: when I invoke addview of TableLayout it make exception . why?

Comment: Do you add which view and how?

Comment: I want to add table row containing two text view

Comment: Which exception do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need following code:

```
TableRow rowHeader = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.rowHeader);

rowHeader.addView(rank);  //Line 39
rowHeader.addView(percentage);
rowHeader.addView(score);
```

`table.addView(rowHeader, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Since they are already defined in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your `logcat`:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

The `TextView`s are already inside the `TableRow`, if you want to fill it programmatically, just remove all the children of your `TableLayout`, create them in code and add them in the `Activity`'s `onCreate` as you just did.

Good luck!